# Moved workspace to dropbox, to a new computer and cannot use git any more

Tags: eclipse, git

Had to move from an old mac to a new mac, figured putting the whole **workspace** folder on dropbox would do the trick (took almost 2 full days for the whole folder to sync thou)

After the sync was done, I realised I don't really need the workspace folder to be on dropbox any more since I only work with the projects from one machine, so I renamed the folder to be **workspace-old**, copied it to the same location where **workspace(-new)** and added it in eclipse.

Now. I cannot use git with my projects from **workspace-old**. I can do NOTHING. Terminal keeps throwing errors.

One of them is

```
error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/YYYYY/XXXXXXXXX.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

I tried deleting and re-adding remote repos, but nothing seems to work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just clone your code from git into new folder.

Comment: The changes I made to the working set that I didn't commit before moving are tooooo big. Thought of cloning as the first thing. But it's not really an option

Comment: Clone and overwrite old files with ones you have in dropbox.